# Select/filter data in excel based on two columnt

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

im new here.

I just want to ask how i can show or filter data in excel so i can get the result like when we use sql syntax :

```
SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE column1 = "a" OR column2 ="b"
```

I already try using filter but the filter only work for one column

Comment: create a formula along the lines of `IF(OR(A1="a",A2="b"),1,0)` and filter for that resulting column being =1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an advanced filter:

From [Filter by using advanced criteria](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP010073942.aspx) - [Multiple criteria, multiple columns, any criteria true](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP010073942.aspx?CTT=1#BMexample3)

- Above your data, insert three empty rows.
- Copy the headings to the top row.
- In the first row under the headings, in column1, put: ="=a".
- In the second row under the headings, in column2, put: ="=b". (These three rows are the criteria for your filter.)
- Select a cell in your data range, and from the 'Data' item on the ribbon select 'Advanced' in the Filter group.
- Ensure that the 'List range:' field has all the data including its headings.
- Ensure that the 'Criteria range:' field includes headings and both rows where you have put criteria information.
- If you want the filter in the same location as the data, ensure that 'Filter the list, in-place' is selected, otherwise select 'Copy to another location' and nominate the cell you want the filtered data to appear in.
- Click OK.

Your data should now have all rows that don't match one of the criteria removed.